# can i call qTip on mouseover in jquery (or any other effience way to call qTip)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, qtip

I have this code below which works fine but seems unnecessary as it loops through all div.test even if i never mouse over them.  I tried putting the .qTip() function inside the mouseover event to be more efficient but that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions on how to make the below code more efficient?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('div.test').each(function () {

            var tooltipHtml = $(this).next('.tooltip').html();
            $(this).qtip({
                content: {
                    text: tooltipHtml
                },
                style: { width: 450 }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: You're probably trying to do something qTip already does for you. Adding qTips should be very efficient. Writing your own code to apply a tooltip on mouseover is useless, as it would take more time to execute than qTip. (It should. If qTip is well-designed.)

Comment: How many of these are you binding?

Comment: @ooo - Do you need all the features of qTip?  If not you may want to check out the drastically lighter version, Simpletip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/

Comment: @Nick Craver - i just need to allow html inside a tooltip

Comment: @Nick Craver - it looks like qTip replaced simpleTip based on the website.  what do you mean by "drastically lighter version"?

Comment: @ooo - Simpletip is still around, it doesn't have all the bells and whistles of qTip but it's considerably smaller/more lightweight.  Look at the code alone, Simpletip's 5kb minified, qTip is 38kb, lots more going on when you bind...hurting performance if you don't need those bells and whistles :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve it a bit like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('div.test').each(function () {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: $(this).next('.tooltip'),
            style: { width: 450 }
        });
    });
});
```

The [`content` option](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#content) takes a jQuery object (referred to as a jQuery DOM array in the documentation), so there's no need to crawl the HTML for each one.  *But*, if you're still binding a large number of these (hundreds or more) performance still may not be what you're after in older browsers.